# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code. I am trying to retrieve just the text "first program". Considering that i know the index say 25 and total length of string is 35.

```
string text="Hello world ! This is my first program";

Response.Write(text.SubString(25,35));
```

But i get the error during runtime "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string"

Comment: Isn't the second argument supposed to be the length of the substring?

Comment: Note you need to have the length parameter correct as well - you'll get ArgumentOutOfRangeException if start+lengthToExtract > actual length of string - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx.  What you probably want is text.SubString(25, 13) - 13 is the length of the text "first program"

Comment: Funny. I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, but with this message: "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parameters for [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) are:

```
public string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
```

You're trying to take 35 characters *after* the 26th character (startIndex is zero-based), which is out of range.

If you just want to get from the 25th character to the end of the string use `text.SubString(24)`

Answer (score 4):

Second argument to `string.Substring()` is the *length*, not the end-offset:

```
Response.Write(text.Substring(25, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Second argument for SubString is the number of characters in the substring.

Simpler way to do it.

```
int startIndex = 25; // find out startIndex
int endIndex = 35;   // find out endIndex, in this case it is text.Length;
int length = endIndex - startIndex; // always subtract startIndex from the position wherever you want your substring to end i.e. endIndex

// call substring
Response.Write(text.Substring(startIndex,length));
```

you can do some operation or call a function to get start/end index values. With this approach you are less likely to get into any trouble related to indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `Substring` is how long you want the substring to be, not the end point of the substring. `25 + 35` is outside the range of the original string, so it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

During this time you can use

**(LINQ ElementAt)** and **(ElementAtOrDefault)** method. However the **ElementAt** extension method would throw the **System.ArguementOutOfRangeException** when the specified index is a negative value or not less than the size of the sequence .

Answer (score 0):

If you used MenuItem, take care like this: [MenuItem("GameObject//Effects/ABC", false, 100)]

double / will make this trouble too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).