# Why do I keep getting this error: "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string" while communicationg with UART

Tags: c#, string, winforms, user-interface, uart

I am making a GUI to communicate with a UART device. For that, I need to show a part of the string received by UART in a rich text box continuously. String Format is like: "$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*" (just for reference). Out of this string, I need to show the data in place of the five zeroes in rtb.
I am doing the following in code.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    private string receiveddata;
    private string substring;
    int startIndex = 17;
    int length = 5;

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, 
            System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {  
        receiveddata = serialPort1.ReadExisting();     
        substring = receiveddata.Substring(startIndex,length);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayText));
    }


    private void displayText(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox2.AppendText(receiveddata);
        richTextBox3.AppendText(substring);    
    }
```

It should write the five zeroes every time into the rtb. It does so the first time but after that, gives the error: "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string"

Comment: I strongly suspect that `receiveddata` *isn't* the string you expect it to be. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Please debug and check on the `receiveddata`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813039/system-argumentoutofrangeexception-startindex-cannot-be-larger-than-length-of-s)

Comment: `SerialPort.DataReceived` is tricky event. It may be rised several times with partial data received and you have to concatenate bytes yourself. Assumption to get at least 17bytes is wrong, be ready to receive 1 or even 0.

Comment: If you're going to follow Jon's suggestion, I strongly recommend putting a breakpoint on the `Substring` line and nowhere before, and let the code run freely up until that point. Debugging this kind of problem can be a little tricky because the delays caused because there's a human in the loop can give you completely different behaviour (I.e. if you're single stepping, there's lots of extra time in which additional data can become available)

Comment: So before `substring = receiveddata.Substring(startIndex,length);` just include `if(receiveddata.length>startIndex)
{
substring = receiveddata.Substring(startIndex,length);
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayText));
}
`

Comment: Upon running debugger, I see that the first time receiveddata gets the whole string and substring gets exactly what it should, while in the second iteration, it only has the first character of string so naturally, the startindex would be larger than it. So, why is it that receiveddata is not picking complete string in second iteration?

Comment: Using SH7's idea, it never displays the string after first time i.e. the if() condition is never met.

Comment: @Ahmed Yes , but it avoids the error you mentioned. So what do you wanna achieve from second iteration.

Comment: @Sinatr I have connected the UART's Tx and Rx in. So, basically the same program is sending the string as well. Your point about partial data receiving makes  sense but by that logic, it should happen the first time as well

Comment: @SH7 The message received is the same every time. I want it to print my desired part of the message everytime the data is received. What happens is that for the first time,  the whole string is received and converted to substring successfully but after that, it never does.

Comment: No, the correct way to interpret this is "You never know how much or how little data will be delivered in each call". The fact that, currently, you have success on the first call and failure on subsequent ones is by no means guaranteed either way.

Comment: Update: Using and slightly modifying @SH7's idea, made some progress:    Did this to the code:                                        
    if(receiveddata.length>startIndex) { substring = receiveddata.Substring(startIndex,length); }                                
         this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayText));

Comment: Update 2/2: Now, after the first iteration, the desired result is displayed but no less than four times in every iteration. After a few, the following error is experienced:                  Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple details to keep in mind.  Like many people have mentioned the serialport data received event won't necessarily be raised with a complete line of your string everytime.  It could be a single character, or even multiple complete lines ("$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*").

Your update:

```
if (receiveddata.length>startIndex)
{
  substring = receiveddata.Substring(startIndex,length);
}
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayText));
```

Gets a little closer to handling the details, but there are still some issues with it.  For example: if receiveddata = "$abc,csd,frvt,v,000", it will try to grab the substring but it won't all be there, causing an exception.  Or what if receiveddata = "$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*$abc,csd,frvt", now you'll be off next time because the leftover string isn't kept.

The solution I came up with waits for an entire "line" to be received before parsing it.  Then it keeps anything extra to add to the next data we receive.

```
private string receiveddata = string.Empty;
private const int startIndex = 17;  // I had to change this from 16 based on the example string you gave.
private const int length = 5;
private const int totalLength = 34;  // The total length of the "line" of text we're expecting ("$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*").


private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,            
  System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  string receivedThisTime = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

  // Update the richTextBox that displays everything received.
  Invoke(new Action(() => displayAllReceivedText(receivedThisTime)));

  // Add what was just received to the string we're currently working on.
  receiveddata += receivedThisTime;

  // If we've received all of the characters in the complete line:
  // "$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*", then we're ready to parse the
  // values we need from it.  This is a while in-case receiveddata contains
  // multiple complete lines - we want to parse them all.
  while (receiveddata.Length >= totalLength)
  {
    // Parse what we need from the string.
    string substring = receiveddata.Substring(startIndex, length);

    // Update the richtextbox that shows the parsed values.
    Invoke(new Action(() => displaySubText(substring)));

    // Now update our string to contain anything that comes after this
    // complete line.  i.e.
    // if receiveddata = "$abc,csd,frvt,v,00000,erty,9,gtyu*$abc,csd,"
    // it should now   = "$abc,csd,"
    receiveddata = receiveddata.Substring(totalLength);
  }
}

private void displayAllReceivedText(string text)
{
  richTextBox2.AppendText(text);
}

private void displaySubText(string text)
{
  richTextBox3.AppendText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You, along with the guys who commented, not only solved my problem but taught me some good shit here.