# Is there a way to use substring in a for loop?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that reads a text file and converts each line to a string array element. Each element in the array looks like this 
"5920 BECDBBAADCBACABEBBED". I need to be able to get rid of the 4 digits and space, and only keep the letters.

Using the code "string[0] = string[0].Substring(5);" works for individual elements, but once I put it into a for loop it throws an error.

```
        string[] canidateAnswers = File.ReadAllLines("C:/Users/Dayton/Desktop/exam.txt");
        canidateAnswers = canidateAnswers.Skip(1).ToArray();

        for (int x = 0; x < canidateAnswers.Length; x++)
        {
            canidateAnswers[x] = canidateAnswers[x].Substring(5);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(canidateAnswers[0]);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is the error that is thrown? You should always check the candidateAnswers[x] length >=6

Comment: *it throws an error* isn't a problem description. What *error* does it throw? On which line? How many lines are in your file? What is the value of `x` when the error happens? What is the exact error message you're getting? That information is right on the screen in front of you, but we can't see it from here, so you should include it in your question so that we have it as well.

Comment: sorry about that, the error is "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."

Comment: You probably have a blank line at the end of your file, also this is about the time you need to learn how to use the debugger to step through code

Comment: Read the words in that error message. They tell you exactly what the problem is (*startindex cannot be larger than length of string*). So what might be the cause of that error? A string that has not enough characters for you to get a substring with a `startindex` of 5. So the problem is that you're trying to take the substring of a line shorter than 5. The debugger can help you figure out which line was the last that worked, and the problem will be with the line after that - what's the issue with that line?

Comment: You have a string with lenght less than 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813039/system-argumentoutofrangeexception-startindex-cannot-be-larger-than-length-of-s) and several dozen others that can be found searching for the exact error message.

Comment: thank you all for the quick responses! one of my string variables was blank because I had an extra line in the text file.

Answer (score 1):

string.Substring() throws an [exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) when the index is larger than the length of the input string. You have a line in your file which is less than 6 characters long, so when you index into one of those lines the exception is thrown. Try checking the length of the string first like so:

```
const int SUB_FROM = 5;

for (int x = 0; x < canidateAnswers.Length; x++)
{
    if (canidateAnswers[x].Length > SUB_FROM)
        canidateAnswers[x] = canidateAnswers[x].Substring(SUB_FROM);
}
```

Comment: thank you! one of the lines in my file was blank as soon as I deleted it, it worked.

Comment: If you feel this answered your question, you can mark it as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers